# Error bound on differentiability of eigenvalues

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a theorem on **differentiabiliy of eigenvalues** that says :
Let $\lambda_{\star}$ be a simple eigenvalues of A and let $v_{\star}$ be its right eigenvector and $u_{\star}$ its left eigenvector. 
Then for $\varepsilon$ small enough, the matrix $A(\varepsilon) = A + \varepsilon \cdot E$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda(\varepsilon)$ close to $\lambda_{\star}$. And $\lambda(\varepsilon)$ is differentiable around $0$ and we have $$\lambda(\varepsilon) = \lambda_{\star} + \varepsilon \frac{u_{\star}^{H}E v_{\star}}{u_{\star}^{H}v_{\star}} + O(\varepsilon^{2})$$

The $3$ matrices I perturbed are : $$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0&  e^{-i\pi/3}& 0\\ 
 0& 0 & e^{i\pi/3}
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 20 & 200\\ 
 0&  e^{-i\pi/3}& 1\\ 
 0& 0 & e^{i\pi/3}
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 200 & 2\cdot10^{6}\\ 
 0&  e^{-i\pi/3}& 1\\ 
 0& 0 & e^{i\pi/3}
\end{pmatrix}$$

So I calculated every *eigenvalues* of **A** and I *perturbed* **A** with a random matrix **E** of norm $1$ and re-calculated its *eigenvalues*. 
The circles I drew are centered with the corresponding eigenvalue and his radius is $\kappa\cdot\varepsilon$ with $\kappa = \frac{u_{\star}^{H}E v_{\star}}{u_{\star}^{H}v_{\star}}$ like the Taylor development in the previous theorem.

But as you can see in the figure below, the eigenvalues *stay* in the circle according to the theorem for the first matrix, but for matrices $2$ and $3$, for $2$ eigenvalues, some of the perturbed eigenvalues are going *outside* which is strange because the theorem **takes into account** every $\kappa$ for each eigenvalues so it is not supposed to go outside each circle.

Of course we have $O(\varepsilon^{2})$ in the Taylor development but as you can see in the first plot, we have $\varepsilon = 5\cdot 10^{-1}$ and the perturbed eigenvalues are not going outside any circles.

And this is a theorem so it's **true** so at a moment there is a numerical instability or too much rounding errors.. but **where** ?

There must a thing with the **condition of the perturbed matrix** but it's never taken into account in this theorem  ?

[image: Perturbated eigenvalues]

Answer (score 1):

If you are genuinely using $\epsilon=0.5$ then $\epsilon^2=0.25$ and you should expect the points to exist within a circle of radius $a\epsilon+b \epsilon^2$ for some constants $a, b$ dependant on the matrix. The fact that for the first matrix all the points lie inside a circle of radius $a\epsilon$ implies that $b\leq 0$. Because $\epsilon$ is so large these corrections have a large impact.

Comment: The radius is $\kappa \varepsilon + b\varepsilon^{2}$ right ?
I didn't get the rest ..
And when I changed the $\varepsilon$ for matrix 2 and 3, all the points were lying into each circle which is strange because the perturbation depends on $\varepsilon$ and the radius too so we expect the same behavior at a lower/larger scale right ? But no, points are going outside circle with a specific $\varepsilon$..  

And I didn't get why for the first matrix you said that it implies b $\leq 0$

Comment: No, if you make $\epsilon$ smaller then the order $\epsilon^2 $ correction term becomes less significant and can be ignored if it is sufficiently small. For larger values you cannot ignore the correction. You are drawing a circle at $r=a\epsilon$ but the theorum only gives that the points are in a circle of radius $r=a\epsilon + b\epsilon^2 + \ldots$ and the value of $a$.

Comment: Yeah so it should fail for the first matrix because we ignored the correction of $\varepsilon^{2} = 0.25$ which cannot be ignored, and it should be pretty accurate for the other 2 matrices because $\varepsilon^{2}$ will be really small right ?

Comment: And just in case, the respective conditions of the 3 matrices are 
$1,   4\cdot 10^{4},   4\cdot 10^{12}$

Comment: For the second matrix, if you make $\epsilon$ smaller do the points move closer to/inside the circle?

Comment: Inside the circles ? Yes

Comment: Then it's just a case that your epsilon is too big because the value of $b/a$ is large for your matrix.

Comment: And if Iet $\varepsilon = 0.05$, the circles are significantly larger and all perturbed eigenvalues are in them.
Could you give more details about the ratio $\frac{b}{a}$ please ?

Comment: If the points are inside a circle of radius $r=a\epsilon + b\epsilon ^2 + \ldots$ then, factoring, $r = a\epsilon (1+b\epsilon/a+\ldots) $. For $r=a\epsilon$ to be a good approximation to the radius then we require $|b\epsilon /a| \ll 1$, and similarly for all the other terms in the sum, thus $\epsilon\ll |a/b|$. The behaviour at large$ \epsilon$ is irrelevant to the theorum. I suggest you read up on asymptomatic analysis if this is confusing you.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! But if my initial $\varepsilon = 5\cdot10^{-3}$, I have data points outside the circles. But if  $\varepsilon = 5\cdot10^{-2}$ or $5\cdot10^{-5}$, my points are inside the circles which is strange because for a larger epsilon is shouldn't work..
For matrices $2$ and $3$, it seems that it fails just for a specific $\varepsilon$, is there a link with the **condition** ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work for large $\epsilon $? Your theorum only says that it does work for sufficiently small epsilon, and says nothing about larger epsilon. Be careful with your logic.

Comment: My bad I though that *irrelevant* means *not coherent* but it's more like *no importance*. Anyway, I don't get why for a really specific epsilon, we have data points outside and if I go lower or upper, points are now lying in the circles..